# How to execute phantomjs php via browser?

Tags: php, phantomjs

i execute this on shell and i get the result

[root@s1 ~]# phantomjs /opt/phantomjs/examples/hello.js
Hello, world!

But how to execute this on php via browser?

Comment: You can directly run js in browser why you need to run pantomjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exec` function in php to issue the same call you do in shell.

```
exec("/opt/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /opt/phantomjs/examples/hello.js", $output);
echo $output;
```

It's preferable to use full paths to binary and scripts to avoid problems with finding fikes, because your php script is likely to be in entirely different location.